# Fetching the vm prerequisites data using automation script

Tags: shell, powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Requirement is  to check the prerequisites details like ip address, subnet id , vpn ,os name etc of vm  which is hosted on azure cloud .

Data has to be find out using automation. So which tool i have to use?
Which language i have to prefer?
If you have any examples please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/) in Microsoft Docs links to commonly used command-line tools, languages, and DevOps tools.